# Fastest approach: Count all products (including variations) in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm wondering if there exist any faster approaches to count all products in WooCommerce (and their child-variations), than this following code-example:

```
function total_product_count() {
    $product_count = 0;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    /* Initialize WP_Query, and retrieve all product-pages */
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    /* Check if array contains any posts */
    if ($loop->have_posts()): 
        while ($loop->have_posts()): 
            $loop->the_post();
            global $product;

            /* Count the children - add count to product_count */
            product_count += count($product->get_children());

        endwhile;

    endif;

    return $product_count;
}
```

On my local XAMPP web-server the function executes in 3 seconds (having 253 products), which is way too long time. The function returns 1269.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-a-count-of-total-product-published

Comment: Farkie: $loop->found_posts only returns 253, course child variations aren't  included in count

Comment: You unfortunately can't optimize this much with native WP functions or classes.

Answer (score 0):

`$product->get_children()` is not always correct in this situation. `get_children()` return child products as well as grouped products if exist.

I hope the better and fastest way is to use wpdb:: MySQL query method. Try the following code

```
echo 'Number of main products => '.main_product_count();
echo 'Number of variations => '. variation_product_count();

function main_product_count() {
    global $wpdb;
    $count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE `post_type` LIKE 'product'");
    return $count;
}

function variation_product_count() {
    global $wpdb;
    $count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE `post_type` LIKE 'product_variation'");
    return $count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

as your naming

> $loop =new WP_Query($args);

try this code

```
$loop->post_count;
 while ($loop->have_posts()){
   global $product;
   /* Count the children - add count to product_count */
    $loop->post_count += count($product->get_children());

 }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP explicitly stated that he's also looking to count child posts. `found_posts` and `post_count` on the original returned post object won't do it.

Answer (score -1):

`WP_Query` has a property which gives you the number of posts found matching the current query parameters:

```
function total_product_count() {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );

    $products = new WP_Query( $args );

    return $products->found_posts;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP explicitly stated that he's also looking to count child posts. `found_posts` and `post_count` on the original returned post object won't do it.